# I kept getting the message like 'failed to create the Java Virtual Machine' on MacOS Mojave

Tags: eclipse, macos, installation

Failed to save 'eclipse.ini': Unable to write file

'/Volumes/Eclipse 2/Eclipse.app/Contents/Eclipse/eclipse.ini' (Unknown (FileSystemError): Error: EROFS: read-only file system, open '/Volumes/Eclipse 2/Eclipse.app/Contents/Eclipse/eclipse.ini')
**This what happened when I try to manipulate what in this ini file as suggested in similar problems.
Here is my error message of saving in visual studio code**

```
-startup
../Eclipse/plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.5.700.v20200207-2156.jar
--launcher.library
../Eclipse/plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.cocoa.macosx.x86_64_1.1.1200.v20200508-1552
-product
org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product
-showsplash
org.eclipse.epp.package.common
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
--launcher.appendVmargs
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.8
-Dosgi.instance.area.default=@user.home/eclipse-workspace
-XX:+UseG1GC
-XX:+UseStringDeduplication
--add-modules=ALL-SYSTEM
-XstartOnFirstThread
-Dorg.eclipse.swt.internal.carbon.smallFonts
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.8
-Dosgi.dataAreaRequiresExplicitInit=true
-Xms256m
-Xmx2048m
--add-modules=ALL-SYSTEM
-Xdock:icon=../Resources/Eclipse.icns
-XstartOnFirstThread
-Dorg.eclipse.swt.internal.carbon.smallFonts
```

**I do not have permission for this file for some reason. Also my previous question someone suggests me that the problem is not installing java jdk but after I installed it, then launch java ee version, same error appears. How do I fix this?
I open the get Info of this ini file, it says dylan(writes/reads). I am confused.
Can someone tell me how to exactly install it.**

**Moreover, I look it up in java official guide of solving this problem, it says**
If you’re seeing this popup when you launch Eclipse itself, or the Eclipse installer on your macOS, this post is for you. First, there’s a bit more details on the Eclipse and JDK bug trackers. To fix this, you will need to uninstall the problematic JDK version and install the latest one on your macOS machine:

1. Run the /usr/libexec/java_home -V command to list all installed JVM versions.
2. Identify the problematic version of the JVM – in my case it was “14, x86_64: "Java SE 14" /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-14.jdk/Contents/Home“.
3. Delete that version – with something like
   “sudo rm -rf /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-14.jdk/“
4. Install the latest matching JVM / JDK – at the time of this writing it is 14.0.1
5. Verify that it appears in the list of installed JVMs with
   /usr/libexec/java_home -V
6. If needed, point the Eclipse.app/Contents/Eclipse/eclipse.ini to the location of the newly installed JVM (-vm parameter)

**I am not sure how it works. For example, how do I identify which one is problematic, and what command should I use in terminal to install it, etc.**

Comment: You definitely need to install JDK 14.0.1 (or 14.0.2), Eclipse on macOS will not run with JDK 14

Comment: I installed it for sure. Same error appears.

Comment: It's definitely not that.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem and I updated eclipse.ini file as following:

> -vm
>
> /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_73.jdk/Contents/Home/bin

I added these lines to update -vm parameters right before -vmargs parameters and it works fine for me. Got from this website -> https://www.journaldev.com/10882/eclipse-ini-vm-arguments-file-location-mac-windows